# Sort in an object

Tags: perl, hash

I have an object ($p), and in the initialization I have `$this->{list} = [];`

Later, I fill up the array with objects of another class (q), and can access them as `@{$self{list}}` in another subroutine in class [p]. I am trying to sort this array, as

```
my @slist = sort $self->point_sort, @{$self->{list}};
```

`point_sort` is defined as a subroutine in class p, and I am getting

```
Can't call method "getQval" on an undefined value at p.pm line 64
```

`getQval` is a subroutine defined in object q, instances of which populate the `{list}`. I am trying to do

```
my $v1 = $a->getQval;
my $v2 = $b->getQval;
```

in the subroutine `point_sort`. Any suggestions? TIA.

Edit:
Changed the call to

```
my @slist = sort { $self->point_sort ($a,$b) } @{$self->{list}};
```

In point_sort, I have now

```
my ($c, $d) = @_;
my $val1 = $c->getVarVal;
```

The error:

```
Can't locate object method "getVarVal" via package "packageP" at ...
```

I think it has something to do with packages, not sure what it is. It is looking in package p, whereas I want it to look at package q.

Edit:
I did a `print` on `$c` above - perl thinks it is an object of class p - a hashtable

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually using `$self->point_sort` as a comparison function here.  It's being *called* immediately (with no arguments and before `$a` and `$b` are set, hence the error), and its return value (if it got that far) would then be used as the comparator.

The easiest fix is to pass `$a` and `$b` explicitly:

```
my @slist = sort { $self->point_sort($a, $b) } @{$self->{list}};
```

Then receive them as regular arguments in `point_sort`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of `sort` are:

```
sort SUBNAME LIST   # Sort the list using named function as the comparison function
sort BLOCK LIST     # Sort the list using the block as the comparison function
sort LIST           # Sort the list using the default comparison function.
```

You want `$self->point_sort` to be used as the comparison function, but you used the third syntax rather than one of the two that allows you to specify a comparison function.

Perhaps you want

```
sort { $self->point_sort($a, $b) } @{ $self->{list} }
```

is clear n